# How to get System Type in VC++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am looking for a function which can return system type i.e. "Windows x64" or "Windows NT x64" etc.

Is there any function which I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a complete document [available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx) that shows exactly how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

[`GetVersionEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx) tells you about the operating system version.

If you want to know whether the underlying system is 32 bit or 64 bit then I recommend reading how [Raymond Chen explains it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx).

Comment: Thank You very much for such a quick reply ! 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx - for example